# Round only int of variable

Tags: php, magento

I am busy with a webshop, and I have an issue:

I display the quantity of the products, and the attribute of the product.

Like:

```
2,4 cm
2,56 dm
```

Now I want to Round the numbers of the variable, but if I use:

```
$qty = round($_product->getBundle_qty());
```

But if I use: `$aantal = $_product->getBundle_qty();` everything works okay, but he doesn't round.

Then the attribute doesn't show anymore ( dm, cm, m ETC)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the $_product->getBunlde_qty() actually a double or a float? Or is it just a string? In that case, you can use:

```
$qty = round(floatval($_product->getBundle_qty()));
```

**Edit:**
Now if you want to keep the cm / dm in behind the string we can take the string and explode it at all the spaces, thus creating an array from the string. The last value in this array will be the 'cm' or 'dm' text.

```
$qtyPieces = explode(" ", $_product->getBundle_qty()); //explode at the space
$qtyPiecesCount = count($qtyPieces); //count all pieces
$qty = round(floatval($_product->getBundle_qty())) . " " . $qtyPieces[$qtyPiecesCount - 1]; //get the last value in the array, count minus 1 because we start counting from 0
```

Comment: It is just a string.. But with this code, he does round, but he doesn't show the attribute.. ( CM, DM ) etc.

Comment: yes, that is because to round it, it needs to be a number. What you can do is explode the string to look for spaces, get the last item in the array and stick it behind the rounded number. Let me edit my answer to show what i mean.

Comment: Fixed it by myself by using explode thanks to you! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it using explode:

```
                            $arr = explode(' ',trim($_product->getBundle_qty()));
                            echo $arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the attribute portion is a string.

1. Round your integers first.

   ```
    //example:
    $qty = round(2.4);
   ```
2. Then add the string attribute back to it.

   ```
    $value = $qty . "cm";
   ```

Comment: Jeh, but CM is a variable.